# How to calculate Pupillary Distance(distance between both eyes retina) in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am going to create an application for iphone/Ipad.I want to calculate the PD (Pupillary Distance).
Please tell me if any solution for this.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. The easy part: use some computer vision library (for example, OpenCV) to get the position of the two retinas. The hard part: remember Pithagoras' theorem:

```
distance = sqrt((x2 - x1) ^ 2 + (y2 - y1) ^ 2)
```

Comment: "software doesn't do what you wish, just what you tell them to do."